# Can't load flash drive on startup of new PC

Tags: windows, boot, installation, bios, usb-flash-drive

I have a fresh OS-less PC. I'm trying to install Win 10 from a flash drive but the system just ignores it. I have entered the BIOS menu and put the USB at the top of things to boot but nothing happens. Holding F12 during boot-up brings up a "softer" BIOS menu (I'm not sure what to call it) with the title "Startup Device Menu" where apparently I can directly select what to boot from. Having my flash in the PC brings up two options in this menu - USB CDROM: Sandisk... and USB KEY: SanDisk... I have tried selected either but again nothing happens and the system acts as if there is no USB. What can I do?

Comment: How did you make the flash drive?

Comment: @Sasho - The person who created the installation media created it the incorrect way.  You will need to use the Media Creation Tool and format the drive.  You can also use Rufus if you use the correct settings.  If you paid for this service you should get an immediate refund.

Comment: @Ramhound  How can you be so sure? I'm sure there are other possibilities and I'd like to explore them (cause that is just about the only thing I can do about it atm)

Comment: @Sasho - What you have tried are the correct actions.  There isn’t that you can do to make the installation media work.  You will need to create it yourself with either Rufus or the Media Creation Tool.

Answer (score 0):

> I have entered the BIOS menu and put the USB at the top of things to boot but nothing happens.

Based on this description you have performed the correct steps.  The fact you are unable to boot into the installation environment means the installation media was created the incorrect way.  The simplest solution to this problem is to create the installation media yourself.

You can either use the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) or [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).

> I have tried selected either but again nothing happens and the system acts as if there is no USB. What can I do?

You will have to recreate the installation media yourself.

> I didn't. A PC store put a Windows 10 copy on it for me.

If you paid for this service I would get an immediate refund.

It has been suggested that you should disable Secure Boot.  This step should absolutely not be performed.  The Windows 10 installation environment is compatible with Secure Boot.  So trying this suggestion will be an absolute waste of your valuable time.